# Quests system with time in a text game using telegram

Tags: c#, time, telegram

Hello i'm trying to make a text-based game in Telegram using c# api.
I have a database that contains:
Player(playerID, username, health, money, missionID, missionDuration).

MissionID and missionDuration can be NULL.

Mission(missionID, description).

When a player sends to the bot the command "/mission", a random mission is assign to the player and a random duration number gets generated.

How can i check if the mission is over?

I made this piece of code that checks if the duration is over:

```
    public static bool Check(double duration)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;

        end = end.AddSeconds(duration);

        while (now < end)
        {
            now = DateTime.Now;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Of course this is wrong because the cpu is always used.
There is a way to better check if a time has passed?

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application? Console application? WPF? It sounds as though what you're looking for is a timer, but it depends on what type of app you're writing.

Comment: It's a Console Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically what you'd do in this situation is create a timer that will expire after a given duration. When the timer expires, the callback will set an event indicating that the interval has ended. Here's one way to do it:

```
using System.Threading;
static private Timer questTimer;
static private ManualResetEvent questExpired = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// in your code where you start the quest

// clears the event to show that the quest has not ended
questExpired.Reset();

// start the timer.
questTimer = new Timer(QuestEndedCallback, null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
```

That creates a timer that starts immediately. After `duration` milliseconds, the timer will expire and call the `QuestEndedCallback` method. The `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)` signifies that it's a "one-shot" timer: it will tick once and then exit.

The `QuestEndedCallback` is:

```
static void QuestEndedCallback(object state)
{
    // Set the timer to indicate that the quest has ended.
    questExpired.Set();
}
```

In your code that does the processing, whenever you want to see if the quest has ended, you check the event:

```
bool questHasEnded = questExpired.WaitOne(0);
```